# skimage.io.imsave "destroys" grayscale image?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, matplotlib, scipy

I have an array of graysale image read in from a color one. If I use matplotlib to imshow the grayscale image, it looks just fine. But when I io.imsave it, it's ruined (by an outrageous amount of noise). However, if I numpy.around it first before io.imsave-ing, then it's significantly better, but black and white are still all swapped (dark regions appear white, and bright regions appear dark)

scipy.misc.imsave, on the other hand, works perfectly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've figured out why. By convention, floats in skimage are supposed to be in the range [0, 1].